# Android Intellij IDEA 12 AIDL

Tags: android, intellij-idea, aidl

I´m trying to create a remote IPC service on Android using AIDL. I found some documents that explains how to create such services in Eclipse, but none that explains the creation process on InteliJ IDEA.

I noticed that the IntelliJ have this feature inside File > New > Android Component > Remote Interface and I used this to create a file called IRemoteService.aidl, with the following contents:

```
package MyApp.Android.RemoteServices;
/**
 * Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
 * Máxima Sistemas de Informática S.A.
 * User: regis.oliveira
 * Date: 27/03/13
 * Time: 23:26
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
 */
/** Example service interface */
interface IRemoteService {
    /** Request the process ID of this service, to do evil things with it. */
    int getPid();

    /** Demonstrates some basic types that you can use as parameters
     * and return values in AIDL.
     */
    void basicTypes(int anInt, long aLong, boolean aBoolean, float aFloat,
            double aDouble, String aString);
}
```

But, when I try to compile the project, the following error appears:

```
android-idl-compiler: D:\Docs\Programming\MyApp.Android.RemoteServices\IRemoteService.aidl:10 interface IRemoteService should be declared in a file called MyApp\Android\RemoteServices\IRemoteService.aidl.
```

Does anybody have already implemented this in IntelliJ? Is there any documentations that shows how to use this feature on it?

Thanks

Comment: I do this. Works fine. Please share a sample project to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi @CrazyCoder. After some tries, I realized that the problem was caused by Eclipse, that was opened at the same time as IntelliJ. So, after closing Eclipse and restarting IntelliJ, everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 4):

After some tries, I realized that the problem was caused by Eclipse, that was opened at the same time as IntelliJ. So, after closing Eclipse and restarting IntelliJ, everything worked as expected.